# How can i create shortcut for curly brackets ?

Tags: atom-editor

I explain the (little) problem, on italian keyboard is literally a pain use the curly brackets, 
and i'm searching a solution for have a easy shortcut in Atom to click and have the curly brackets !!

Comment: [This video](http://vimeo.com/87902013) claims to explain how to create custom shortcut bindings in Atom.

Comment: yes i saw it, but i don't know when i can find all the methods i can call on the object such as tree-view, pane, editor and so on ....

Comment: Then you need to make your question more specific.

Comment: click Alt+c (example) to have th {} in atom !

Comment: Solved !  i build a package like the Hello World example on the atom site ! easy